# Opera error in html5 : data-xxxx custom tag issue rewriting

Tags: jquery, html, opera

i come now cause Opera is giving me more job than what a think , the problem is the next:

```
$('.colourbox').click( function()
{
    $('.colourbox').css('border-color','#a3a3a3');
    $('.colourbox').attr('data-selected','no');
    $('.colourbox').children().css('border-color','transparent');
    $(this).css('border-color','#222');
    $(this).children().css('border-color','#fff');
    $(this).attr('data-selected','yes');
    }
```

I have this code , and the problem is the next , when i do it first time , $(this).attr('data-selected','yes'); create the tag and the value , but when i try to rewrite in a second click width $('.colourbox').attr('data-selected','no'); , the data doesn't change.

Comment: So this works in other browsers?

Comment: @Pointy yes , that works on firefox 3.6.11 and chrome 6.0.472.63 . P.D: html5 web.

Comment: Any reason you are using a custom attribute instead of jQuery's .data() ?

Comment: I'll try to see that , i didnt know .data() function . Anyway ill try to see why its happening , and maybe it can be for answer 2 tomorrow ill answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.colourbox').attr('data-selected','no');`

^ This selects *every* element so it may be returning all or the last value of the entire set. Try querying one at a time, eg `.eg(0)` to ensure and then refactor based on this.

Comment: Im not sure this is the answer , but i have done it like tando says in the comment . All about the problem is answered in robertc answer comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be [working fine for me](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/jquery-data.html), if you query the attribute value before and after the change it always reports what I would expect.  How are you determining it's not working?  Is it just that Dragonfly is not updating to reflect changes in the DOM?

Comment: I was determininng it , cause the result comes in another part Graphically. But i have put that little part, cause i was sure the problem was there. Seeing this  $('.colourbox').attr('data-selected','no'); after that the result , wasnt no at all .colourbox . Maybe can it be a problem of the selector . and data-new custom attributes . I dont know , but i have done it width .data() jquery function. Thx anyway. I think it can be the meder answer , but im not sure , illput him the right then cause is near to the real answer.